# Logstash Kafka Input , Logstash worker ordering in data consumption

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have used Logstash for Kafka to Elastic search sync.
The input topic has 8 partitions and I have used consumer_threads=8 to consumer the Kafka topic in parallel.

input {
kafka {
bootstrap_servers => "bootstrapServer"
topics => "topicName"
codec => json
group_id => "groupName"
id => ""
consumer_threads => 8
}
}

After the input section, I have a filter and Output in Logstash logic.

How can I increase the Logstash worker parallelism without affecting the ordering of data in a kafka partition?

Does Logstash using an in-memory queue in between input and (filter and output)?
How to ensure that data from a single partition is consumed by a single filter and output thread of Logstash.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple worker threads process data in parallel and also preserve the order of data. Even with a single thread logstash does not preserve the order of data by default, you need to set pipeline.workers to 1 and also set pipeline.ordered to 1.

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple logstash pipeline processes with pipeline.workers=1 & pipeline.ordered to 1 to attain some parallelism without breaking message processing order  ?

Comment: No, messages will be processed out of order unless they all go through a single thread.

Comment: Keep consumer-group name same, and run multiple logstash pipelines with pipeline.workers=1 & pipeline.ordered to 1. In that case, will it not run in parallel by retaining order at partition level?

Comment: Retaining order within a partition will work, between partitions will not work.